# Mongoose Model Methods: Properties don't save?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a method on a mongoose model that will populate some fields based on an object I pass in.

```
let mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    street: { type: String, default: 'No' }
});

mySchema.methods.populate = function(o) {
    this.age = o.age + 10;
});
```

Elsewhere, i'll initialize an instance and run the method:

```
let newThing = new MySchema();
newThing.populate({ age: 12 });
newThing.save();
```

This successfully saves a new object in mongo with no properties other than the default street name. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you exporting your schema? because there is no other error in your code.

Comment: @Khurram If he would not export the Schema, would he be able to save even the default value?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this code which will work.

In **server.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    var Model = require('./model')

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('**dbUrl**')

    var NewData = new Model({
        name: 'Tolsee'
    })

    NewData.populate({ age: 15 })

    NewData.save(function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }else{
            console.log('Your data is saved successfully')
        }
    })
```

In **model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

const customSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    street: { type: String, default: 'No' }
}) 

// Custom function
customSchema.methods.populate = function(o) {
    this.age = o.age
    return this.age
}

// create the model to export 
var custom = mongoose.model('customModel', customSchema)

module.exports = custom
```

First, You will need to create a model in order to use the schema. Instance of these models are documents which can use the custom methods you define.